# Chrome extension - Make injected element open a html page contained within the extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to inject an  tag into an object, then make that  tag take you to an about page, stored inside of the extention itself. Is there any way to do this? Here is my content.js file:

```
var text  = document.createElement("a");
text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("About BSR"))
var yourDIV = document.getElementsByClassName("www-user-info")[0];
yourDIV.appendChild(text);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions recognise the custom html templates for the extension popup menu and the options page, but I'm not sure if you're allowed to define templates which can be navigated via anchor tags / href.

One solution is to add code to either popup.js or the content.js to open a modal window in the current window and show the "about" information for the extension.

I've used a similar approach for an extension I'm currently working on.